# Comparing a number to each value in array

Tags: php, function

I have users submit tempos(number) and I would like to compare that number to an array of preset numbers and return one value that is the next number up from it.

For example:

- Submitted tempo - 145
- Numbers in preset array - 104, 116, 128, 140, 152, 164, 176
- Desired return - 152

I have been messing around with the `array_filter` php function but I haven't come up with anything worth posting here yet. I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas about how I might achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such questions should be posted in StackOverflow. But there you go:

```
$numbers = array( 104, 116, 128, 140, 152, 164, 176 );
$tempo = 145;
$found = false;
ksort( $numbers ); // sort in an ascending order
foreach( $numbers as $number ) { if( $number > $tempo ) { $found = $number; break; } }
print_r( $found ); // int|false
```

Comment: Yea, I thought that just as I posted it, but thank you for your response. This is almost exactly what I was looking for! The only issue now is that if the submitted tempo is the same as a number in the array, I would like for it to show the next number up. Currently it still shows that same number. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help.